# How can I represent this idea to the database design?

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

I am new to database design, I am trying to build a database of shopping system.

Assume we have a Customer table and a Staff table.

The requirement is:

1. To allow part of the customers to have privilege of "Item return & refund".
2. To allow part of the staff to have the authority to process the refund.

My idea is to **simply add a column with a Boolean value to "Flag" which customer or which staff has the authority or not?**

Is that correct to solve this problem? Any potential problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be correct for a simplistic design. However, if you want to be able to expand on your website or if your needs grow over time, you may need to allow for more detailed permissions. A user_permissions table and an employee_permission table would be desirable in that case.

Comment: If there is no more detailed permissions other than I previously mentioned. To simply "Flag" will be sufficient?

Comment: I maybe on the maniac side but I would still build my database to allow for this situation. You never know when you will need this and it's always when you don't build your database properly that you discover you need to expand on that feature you haven't developped. Then hello nightmares and headaches when trying to give your database the proper structure without losing data.